# JsonConvert.SerializeObject is not working in .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

JsonConvert.SerializeObject is not working in .net core 3.1 whereas it is working in .net core 2.2, I want to convert Json array to string

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you don't show us what you are doing, we can't help you. Post the code that is failing.

Comment: Can you share your code?JsonConvert.SerializeObject is used to serialize an json object to json string.If you want to serialize json array with JsonConvert.SerializeObject, you need to convert json array to json object.